# YouTube downloader code creates unplayable videos

Tags: java

I tried to download youtube video (using the same link like keepvid). The file that I got is 4kB larger than one downloaded via browser, and it cannot be played. Can anybody tell me why, and what I'm doing wrong?

Additionally, when I print both files line by line, they show equal data.

The code that I used for downloading is below:

```
try {
  URL hr= new URL("link");
   URLConnection conn= hr.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestProperty("Uzer-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
   conn.connect();

   
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
             
   File file=new File("video.flv");
   PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
             
   String line="";
              
   while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

       System.out.println(line);
        
       pw.println(line);
                 
       }
              
   pw.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: First of all, I would fix `Uzer-Agent` with `User-Agent`. Then, you should not attempt to write a binary file with a `PrintWriter`, which is intended for text. Use a `OutputStream` instead.

Comment: "The file that I got is 4kB larger than one downloaded via browser" "they show equal data"---these two statements are incongruent.

Comment: You do know that it is  harder to download youtube videos than to just  to this? Or do you have a direct link to the actual flv?

Comment: @OskarKjellin I have direct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, although reading *might* be done with `br.readLine()` (not sure, I'd read it with `br.read( char[ 4096 ], off, len )`, but writing with `pw.println` is definitely wrong, as it adds a line-break at the end of each line - something you don't want to see in a binary file.

I'd put it like

```
char[] buff = new char[ 4096 ];
int offset = 0;
while( -1 != br.read( buff, offset, 4096 ) ){
  pw.write( buff );
  offset += 4096;
}
```

You can also use Input/Output-Streams here, as you don't need to do a character-conversions.

Comment: Character streams must be avoided not because you don't *need* character conversion, but because you *must not use* character conversion. This is not open to free choice.

Comment: I'd go for streams (not reader/writer) in the 1st place, but I think, that in most cases reader/writer would work just fine, with some overhead of course. It can get tricky if you along with binary data would have to download some UTF-8 encoded text - that's where reader/write WILL become handy.

Comment: Reading/writing binary data with character streams simply makes no sense at all---and in addition to that, it is not reliable. Your point about the distinction between binary data and UTF-8 encoded text is invalid: if you use a character stream, it sees *everything* as UTF-8 encoded text (or whatever encoding is in effect), and that is precisely what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read binary files (like `flv`) as if they were text files, using `readLine()` and so on. You must use the unformatted `read()` and `write()` methods in `InputStream` and `OutputStream` respectively.